# Edit Lines of list box items

Tags: vb.net, listbox, streamreader, readline

'I have a listbox that I copy multiple lines of a textfile into. I want to remove the first 20 characters of each list item. I also want to update the contents of the listbox anytime the source file is updated with a new line. The listbox may be replaced my textboxes. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Try
        Dim StrmRdr As New StreamReader("C:\Users\e70605\Desktop\alarms.txt")
        Dim word As String = ""
        Dim words(9999) As String


        Dim i As Integer = 0

        'this Do Until Loop was for a Listbox I initially started with
        Do Until StrmRdr.Peek = -1
            'catch a word at a time file file
            word = StrmRdr.ReadLine()

            'send readline into words
            words(i) = word

            'tell where the word should go to 
            ListBox1.Items.Add(words(i))

            'go to the next line. until lines are finished.
            i = i + 1

        Loop
```

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem and ask a question.

Comment: Hello Plutonix. I don't get you clearly, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this line `word = StrmRdr.ReadLine()` put this line `word = word.SubString(20, word.Length - 20)` That will get you just the last part of the line read in. `Substring()` is a good thing to know when working with strings. [SubString MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

The next part is a little more tricky. You will need to setup a timer to scan the file to see if it has changed. I would check the file info to see if the last modified date/time has changed since reading in new data. That means you will have to keep track of the last modified date/time.

Side Note:

I wouldn't use an Array to read in lines of a file. I would recommend using a List. The way to define a List is as such `dim myList as new List (Of String)`
then to add a new element to the list you just used `myList.Add("new String")`. For more info see [List MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Technicality: You don't need word.substring(20,word.length-20). You can just say word.substring(20). If you give just one param, substring takes from the given position to the end.

Comment: True, I just prefer keeping it all uniform, which I guess is more preference than anything.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jay and Jagler. The listbox needs to be updated dynamically. I want it such that the new lines (added to the source file) will be appended to the bottom of the listbox.                                                            Secondly, I have a timer which when fired, makes the next list item the 'listbox.selecteditem'. I want a code such that if a line of the source file contains certain set of words (eg."below par"), either it should not be added to the list items or the selectedindex should be the next one.

Comment: `ListBox1.Items.Add()` will append the new line on to the bottom of the listbox. To check to make sure that the item is not already in the list all you have to do is use `ListBox1.Items.Contains()`, It returns a Boolean value. To answer your off topic problem, just use logic to see if you wont add the item or if it should be selected next. By selected next are you trying to insert into a certain position in the listbox or are you trying to keep track of the selection order of the items in order to hit a button and have it go to a specific item in the listbox?

Comment: For the "off topic problem", I resolved it by using RemoveAt property. Thanks so much.  I guess your answer on the dim myList as new list (Of String) ... myList.add("new string") should resolve the problem. I am however unable to do this. Maybe reading the List MSDN confused me some more. Sorry if I sound disturbing or not too smart. I am new to programming and I am happy for help from people like you.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know when the file is updated?

If your program controls the updates, then you can just rebuild the listbox every time there's an update. Just put a function to rebuild the listbox and call as part of an update.

If the file can be updated by processes outside your control, whether another program or a user editing with Notepad or whatever, then as jagler says, you'd have to create a timer and check for updates periodically. Store the time you read the file somewhere. Every time your timer fires, call File.GetLastWriteTime and compare the last write time on the file to the time you last read. If it's newer, re-read and update the last read time.

Do you really need to update the listbox dynamically while the user is looking at the screen? I don't know your application. I almost always if not always just get the latest data at the time I paint the screen. If the user closes the window and re-opens, or in the case of a web app refreshes the window, then I re-read. Occassionally for a desktop app I'll create a "refresh" button.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jay and @jagler. The listbox needs to be updated dynamically. I want it such that the new lines (added to the source file) will be appended to the bottom of the listbox.